# использование php файла как html

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

я использую VS Code и при установленном `Life Server` расширении, все HTML файлы открываются нормально, но стоит мне перевести формат в php, чтобы использовать именно этот язык, локальный сервер открывает мне просто дерево файлов и всё. могу ли я как то открывать php файлы так же, как и html?

Comment: "нормально" это как?

Comment: "все HTML файлы открываются нормально" - в браузере? А какой у вас локальный веб-сервер установлен и установлен ли? PHP-файлы могут открываться в браузере именно при наличии веб-сервера.

Comment: @Эникейщик, т.е. чтобы я видел весь процесс вёрстки, как при работе с html

Comment: @Quazimorda, да, файлы открываются в браузере, локально. у меня стоит расширение для VS Code "Live Server". обязательно ли ставить тот же "Open Server"?

Comment: @Joker, расширение "Live Server" для VS Code позволяет видеть только результаты изменения в файлах без перезагрузки страницы в браузере. Вы меняете файл в VS Code, сохраняете файл и он сразу обновляется в браузере. Больше это расширение НИЧЕГО не делает. Для работы с php-файлами, чтобы браузер выполнял их код, вам на компьютере необходимо поставить настоящий веб-сервер. Тот же Open Server подойдёт.

Comment: понял вас, не думал, что оно прям так сильно нужно будет, спасибо